# Which property of Jacobi Symbol is used $\left(\frac{x^e}p\right)\left(\frac{x^e}q\right)=\left(\frac xp\right)\left(\frac xq\right)$

Tags: number-theory

While deriving a Jacobi symbol, this derivation is done in a document, but did not explain the property that is used. $p,q$ are prime, $e$ is odd.

Comment: It seems only true if $e$ is an odd number.

Comment: Yes, e is odd.. can you explain how we can deduct like this if e is odd? I am really new in number theory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $e=2k+1$ for some $k$, then $x^e = x\cdot\left(x^k\right)^2=xu^2$ for $u=x^k$. So $$\left(\frac{x^e}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{xu^2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{u}{p}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac{x^e}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{x^{e-2}}{p}\right)\left(\frac{x^2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{x^{e-2}}{p}\right)$$
Now repeat until only $x^1$ is left.